# iOS enable to play audio after return from other music app

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, avaudioplayer, audio-player

I am working on music app.

Here is the case which I want to fix:
I open AppleMusic app > play something > open my app > click play > music does not play. Why and how to fix it?

I use that but still does not work

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code shows you if another app is playing sound in the backgroud

```
var otherAudioPlaying = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().isOtherAudioPlaying
```

If so, try this:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, error: nil)
```